# how to use php to read a compressed gzip file

Tags: php, ruby, gzip

I am trying to convert a <strike>python</strike> ruby program to php and am confused as to how to read compressed gz files using php. in <strike>python</strike> ruby we used

```
if File.exists?(asset_file + '.gz')
                Zlib::GzipReader.open(asset_file + '.gz') do |file|
                    asset_data = file.read
                end
            elsif File.exists?(asset_file)
                File.open(asset_file) do |file|
                    asset_data = file.read
                end
            end
```

after looking at the php docs it would seem that we would have to know the file length but this is variable not all the gzip files are same size.

What would the best way be to read the gzip file and give its contents out (note gzip file only contains one item inside)

Comment: PHP includes a stream wrapper to read gzipped files directly, see http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.compression.php

Comment: Your code is not python, it's ruby.

Comment: removing ruby tag